# Замена QProcess

Tags: c++, процесс, поиск-библиотек

Ищу библиотеку на замену `QProcess`.

Требования:

- Запуск/Останов дочерних процессов
- События изменения статуса процесса
- Кроссплатформенность

Основные задачи: запуск, останов, слежение за статусом.

UPD: Зачем это нужно:

Есть утилита, написанная с использованием QProcess из Qt.

Назначение утилиты - запуск стороннего приложения с набором параметров.

Утилита использует механизм слотов/сигналов для слежения за статусом дочерних процессов.

По некоторым соображениям потребовалось исключить Qt из зависимостей.

Comment: есть boost.process

Comment: @user7860670 насколько я понял, boost::process больше подходит для получения вывода процесса. Мне же больше интересен перезапуск при аварийной остановке.

Comment: Ничего не мешает это сделать посредством boost.process.

Comment: @user7860670 не могли бы вы привести пример кода, который асинхронно отслеживает статус процесса про помощи `boost::process`?

Comment: есть метод `running`

Comment: ну очень странный вопрос, вы читали https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#running-a-process ?

Comment: @S.Nick документация по Qt у меня перманентно открыта в нескольких вкладках.